# Find first and last list within a list with a matching property

Tags: python, list, find

Long time lurker, first time poster..

I have a extremely large text file (1,184,834 rows) containing some information regarding flight plans for a specific day in Europe. Every column represents a new key, and every row is a new segment of the flight. I have so far managed to extract the data i need for my analysis into a list of lists with the following code:

```
import pprint
import csv
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=200)

text = open('E:/Downloads/TNFL09/20120506_m1.so6', 'r')

def clean_data(text, rows):
    newlist = []
    reader = list(csv.reader(text, delimiter=' '))

    for n in xrange(0, len(reader)):
       newlist.append(reader[n][1:6]+reader[n][9:12]+reader[n][16:18])  

    return newlist[:rows]


data = clean_data(text,90)
pp.pprint(data)
```

The output looks as follows:

`['UAFM', 'EGKK', 'A333', '083914', '084141', 'CMB595', '120506', '120506', '156912756', '91'],`

`['KEWR', 'VABB', 'B772', '005500', '010051', 'UAL48', '120506', '120506', '156912546', '1']`

`['KEWR', 'VABB', 'B772', '010051', '010310', 'UAL48', '120506', '120506', '156912546', '2']`

The interesting items for this problem is start/end time(#3 & #4), flight ID(#8) and sequence number(#9).

Every flight consists of number of consecutive sequence numbers. So to get the whole flight one must extract all the sequence numbers for that flight ID.

**What i want to do** is to extract the start and end time for every flight. My initial thoght was to loop through each list in the list and compare the sequence number to the previously iterated list. However i am a beginner to Python and gave up after a few days of googling.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: indices 1 and 2 look like the destination airport code and airplane type, respectively.  Did you mean 3 and 4 for start/end time?  Also, there's no index 10; python uses 0-based indexing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'key' in this specific context- is it a different flight?

Comment: Are they already sorted by flight ID and/or sequence number?

Comment: roippi, yes you are right. It's; Dep aerodrome, arr aerodrome, aircraft, start time, end time, callsign, start date, end date, flight ID, sequence

Comment: I'm not sure what its sorted by, but within each flight ID it's sorted by sequence number.

Every key is a new segment. And for each new segment = sequence +1 if its not the first in the sequence ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, assuming your list-of-lists is sorted by sequence number (looks like they are) is to run it through a generator to aggregate each flight together:

```
def aggregate_flights(flights):
    out = []
    last_id = ''
    for row in flights:
        if row[-2] != last_id and len(out) > 0:
            yield (last_id,out)
            out = []
        last_id = row[-2]
        out.append((row[3],row[4])) #2-tuple of (start,end)
    yield (last_id,out)
```

Which gives for your example input:

```
list(aggregate_flight(agg))
Out[21]: 
[('156912756', [('083914', '084141')]),
 ('156912546', [('005500', '010051'), ('010051', '010310')])]
```

A bit messy, but you get the idea.  For each flight you'll have a list of 2-tuples of `(start,end)` which you can further process to get the overall `(start,end)` for that flight.  You could even modify the generator to *just* give you the overall `(start,end)`, but I tend to like to do my processing in smaller, modular chunks that are easy to debug.

If your inputs are *not* sorted, you'll need to accumulate your data using a `defaultdict`.  Give it a `list` factory and append a `(start,end)` tuple for each line.

**edit:** as requested, here's the modification to only yield a single `(start,end)` pair per flight:

```
def aggregate_flights(flights):
    last_id,start,end = None,None,None
    for row in flights:
        if row[-2] != last_id and last_id is not None:
            yield (last_id,(start,end))
            start,end = None,None
        if start is None:
            start = row[3]
        last_id = row[-2]
        end = row[4]
    yield (last_id,(start,end))
```

At this point I'd note that the output is getting too ugly to abide (an `(id,(start,end))` tuple, ugh) so I'd move up to a `namedtuple` to make things nicer:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Flight = namedtuple('Flight',['id','start','end'])
```

So now you have:

```
def aggregate_flights(flights):
    last_id,start,end = None,None,None
    for row in flights:
        if row[-2] != last_id and last_id is not None:
            yield Flight(last_id,start,end)
            start,end = None,None
        if start is None:
            start = row[3]
        last_id = row[-2]
        end = row[4]
    yield Flight(last_id,start,end)

list(aggregate_flights(agg))
Out[18]: 
[Flight(id='156912756', start='083914', end='084141'),
 Flight(id='156912546', start='005500', end='010310')]
```

Much nicer.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow here. Could you point me in the right direction in the pyth doc regarding this syntax?

Comment: @PeterAxelsson which part?  The output?  The generator expression?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with generators. After your answer I tried to read up a bit to get a better understanding but it's still not that clear to me HOW to use them. If it's not much trouble for you i'd would appreciate a step-by-step explanation in the code above. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I just figured it out. But how do i modify it (or create a new generator) to extract only the first and last start/end-pair? @roippi

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if your lists are already sorted by flightID and sequence number, to do that you could do the following on your list of lists:

```
from operator import itemgetter
#use sort if the original list is not necessary to maintain, 
#if it is use sorted and send it to a new variable
flightInfo.sort(key = itemgetter(8,9))
```

The above sorts first by flight number and then by sequence number.  To extract what you want, you can do:

```
prev, startTime = None, None
results = []

for i, info in enumerate(flightInfo):
    if prev == None or prev != flight[8]:
         if prev != None:
              # use a list if you are going to have to modify these values
              results.append((prev, startTime, flightInfo[i-1][4])) 

         startTime = flight[3]
         prev = flight[8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map keyword. Being "full_list" the list of flights:

```
# python.py

time = [] # Is a dictionaries list. Each dictionary contains: {flight_id: [start, end]}

result = [] # We going to store results here.

def extract(flight, result):
   """ param flight: list containing flight's data. """
   global result # Give function access to result variable.
                 # If not, "result" is passed as a value copy.

   result.append({flight[9]: [flight[3], flight[3]]})

map(extract, result)
```

and that should do the work.